# pgsql concat() functionality(almost)

Tags: postgresql

Part of the MySQL query that I'm trying to convert to pgSQL :

```
LEFT JOIN {$_TABLES['comments']} c ON c.sid = concat('fileid_' ,a.lid )
```

This got messy since it's concatenating a string with a column(a.lid), which isn't supported by the SQL 92 || operator(important!). Any idea's how to redo this part of the query for pgSQL?

Comment: I don't know where you get the idea that || operator cannot concatenate string with column. If this would be true it would make the operator pretty much useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL 8.3 and up supports `||` operator as long as at least one of the operands is a string. Concatentation of column with string literal works as well. What version are you using?

Comment: Yea I was trying it on an older version.

Comment: According to the manual, the `||` string concatenation operator is supported on older versions too, such as version 7.4 (the earliest version with online docs).

Comment: You can always cast the integer one, as in:
'file_id' || CAST (a.lid AS text)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that if you concatenate a null to anything else, all you'll get is null.

Comment: Correct. Not sure if that's pertinent to this question though.